# Excel IF statements & drop down lists

Tags: excel

I'm in the process of putting together a spreadsheet and have an issue I'd like to resolve. 
Basically, what I want to achieve is this:
When a drop down list option of 'test (gcse & functional skills)' is selected in column D, columns E & F are populated with a drop down list containing numbers (0 to 100) .  But, if any other option is selected on column D then the user can manually enter a value they want (which will be numeric) in columns E & F.
I'm hoping it can be done through a function but it may need VB - which I've very little experience of.
Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Steve

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remember that this is not a code writing service but rather a forum to get focused help on coding errors. You are required to provide the work you have done and the errors found. To get you started I do think you need VBA for this as you can't change Data Validation from a List to a Custom Formula dynamically without it. You would place a Worksheet_Change event on your sheet to detect changes in column D and based on the target value you can change the type of Data Validation. Hope this gets you started. If you run into errors you can repost your question with your code.

Comment: Apologies, I had tried various scenarios but hadn't had any success at the point of writing, however; I will take on board your comments & give it further investigation tomorrow.

Comment: No problem. One further suggestion is to use the Macro Recorder and create the data validation for each situation. You can then review the code created and adapt it into the Worksheet_change event. Regards.